# How to strip pronunciation guidelines from text?

Tags: text, awk, sed, normalization, wikipedia

I'm working with a bunch of text from Wikipedia where I would like to remove the various pronunciation guidelines that are included with the entries. For example, given the following entries:

```
Sigmund Freud (/ˈfrɔɪd/ FROYD; German: [ˈziːkmʊnt ˈfʁɔʏt]; born Sigismund Schlomo Freud; 6 May 1856 – 23 September 1939) was an…
Plato (/ˈpleɪtoʊ/; Greek: Πλάτων Plátōn, pronounced [plá.tɔːn] in Classical Attic; 428/427 or 424/423 – 348/347 BC) was a…
Napoleon Bonaparte (/nəˈpoʊliən ˈboʊnəpɑːrt/; French: [napɔleɔ̃ bɔnapaʁt]; 15 August 1769 – 5 May 1821) was a…
Michael Faraday FRS (/ˈfæ.rəˌdeɪ/; 22 September 1791 – 25 August 1867) was an…
Martin Luther (/ˈluːθər/; German: [ˈmaɐ̯tiːn ˈlʊtɐ]; 10 November 1483 – 18 February 1546), O.S.A., was a…
Louis Pasteur (/ˈluːi pæˈstɜːr/, French: [lwi pastœʁ]; December 27, 1822 – September 28, 1895) was a…
```

I would ideally like to end up with something more along the lines of the following:

```
Sigmund Freud (born Sigismund Schlomo Freud; 6 May 1856 – 23 September 1939) was an…
Plato (428/427 or 424/423 – 348/347 BC) was a…
Napoleon Bonaparte (15 August 1769 – 5 May 1821) was a…
Michael Faraday FRS (22 September 1791 – 25 August 1867) was an…
Martin Luther (10 November 1483 – 18 February 1546), O.S.A., was a…
Louis Pasteur (December 27, 1822 – September 28, 1895) was a…
```

Is there a programmatic way to do that?

Comment: what have you tried? how do you differentiate pronunciation guideline and text?.. simple enough regex is possible for given sample, but that won't be robust

Answer (score 2):

***sed*** solution:

```
sed 's|/[^/]*/[^,;]*[,;]\(.*\[[^][]*\][^;]*;\)* *||g' file
```

The output:

```
Sigmund Freud (born Sigismund Schlomo Freud; 6 May 1856 – 23 September 1939) was an…
Plato (428/427 or 424/423 – 348/347 BC) was a…
Napoleon Bonaparte (15 August 1769 – 5 May 1821) was a…
Michael Faraday FRS (22 September 1791 – 25 August 1867) was an…
Martin Luther (10 November 1483 – 18 February 1546), O.S.A., was a…
Louis Pasteur (December 27, 1822 – September 28, 1895) was a…
```

---

- `/[^/]*/[^,;]*[,;]` - matches *pronunciation* section `/.../` with optional following words `[^,;]*` and ending with `,` or `;`
- `\(.*\[[^][]*\][^;]*;\)*` - matches *pronunciation* section `[...]` surrounded with optional words (presented by `.*` and `[^;]*`) and ending with `;`. All this match marked as optional `(....)*`